# How does Polkadot work?

Tags: blockchain, sidechain, polkadot

How does Polkadot enable the integration of different blockchains? What are the core components of that process?. I would like to understand the difference between two way pegging and the Polkadot technology.

Comment: Roland, Would you consider editing your question to remove the sentence that begins with "Additionally" to focus on the first sentence.  I really would love to know the answer to that question, and would vote to re-open it.  Here is how I would suggest you word it to overcome the "too broad" ground for closure: "How does Polkadot enable the integration of different blockchains?  What are the core components of that process?"